# Date Time Picker setState messing up my state

Tags: react-native, redux

I have an async function where I load my data and update state:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      userData: {},
      isDateTimePickerVisible: false,
    };
  }

componentDidMount() {
    this.getUser();
}

getUser = async () => {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    const tenantID = navigation.getParam('userID', '0');
    await this.props.getUserByID(tenantID); // Wait for action to complete
    this.setState({
      userData: this.props.userData
    });
};
```

Then I use the state data to populate the Input value of my render(). However, I added a DateTimePicker to my component where opens the DateTimePicker in the onFocus Input:

```
<Input
    style={styles.valueText}
    onFocus={this.showDateTimePicker}
    value={getFormattedDate(EndDate)}
/>
<DateTimePicker
    isVisible={this.state.isDateTimePickerVisible}
    onConfirm={this.handleDatePicked}
    onCancel={this.hideDateTimePicker}
    date={EndDate}
/>
```

The methods to handle the show/hide/update date:

```
showDateTimePicker = () => {
    this.setState({
      isDateTimePickerVisible: true
    });
  };

  hideDateTimePicker = () => {
    this.setState({
      isDateTimePickerVisible: false
    });
  };

  handleDatePicked = date => {
    const obj = { ...this.state.userData };
    obj.LeaseStartDate = date;
    this.setState({
      userData: obj
    });
    this.hideDateTimePicker();
  };
```

When I first open the page, it is doesn't have any data in the this.state.userData. But, if I delete the methods 'showDateTimePicker' and 'hideDateTimePicker' the this.state.userData has the data when I first load the page. Why is it happening?

Thanks

Even if I leave the methods without the setState, it does work. However, if I remove these methods it just work.

```
showDateTimePicker = () => {

  };

  hideDateTimePicker = () => {

  };
```

Comment: can you console.log(this.state) inside showDateTimePicker and HideDateTimePicker?

Comment: Nothing happens when I do it. These methods are not called if I don't click on the <Input EndDate

Comment: So nothing shows when you click the input and it becomes in focus?

Comment: It shows: userData: {}, isDateTimePickerVisible: false.

Comment: I don't know why it is setting the userData: {} even though I don't click on the button